# Segmentation fault : unexpected behaviour of STL MAP

Tags: c++, dictionary

I am using STL map in my code. One of the function is using the MAP which is declared globally and it is giving segmentation fault. But if i make that MAP as local variable its working fine. Following function creating problem.

```
typedef map<int,string> DebugAllocPtrList_t;    
DebugAllocPtrList_t DebugAllocPtrList;    

int g_DebugAllocCount;


void DebugAllocNew(void *x, char *szFile, int iLine)
{        
    char szBuf[512];
    szBuf[0]=0; 
    sprintf(szBuf,"%s line %d", szFile, iLine);

    printf("Memory already allocated");

    DebugAllocPtrList[(int)x] = szBuf; //here it gives fault when declared globally.        
    g_DebugAllocCount++;    
}
```

If i run this function independently its working.But when i put this function in to  my actual code 
it gives segmentation fault.And if  i make  **DebugAllocPtrList_t DebugAllocPtrList;** variable local then also i will work.

Comment: `DebugAllocPtrList` _local_ to what? To `DebugAllocNew` function? But in this case it's always destructed at scope exit... Please clarify.

Comment: Please try to provide a minimal example that demonstrates the fault.

Comment: actually that is some time i am passing integer or some time float but that is not creating problem because same function will work fine if i declare DebugAllocPtrList_t DebugAllocPtrList variable local to same function

Comment: Also use: char szBuf[512] = {'\0'} if that's what you meant with the szBuf[0]=0;

Comment: Why are you calling it a list when it's actually a map?

Comment: Could you please clarify what you precisely mean by _"locally"_? If you declare that variable "locally" to `DebugAllocNew` function, the map instance is always destroyed when function exits, so the bug may just be hidden in that case (the map is created, a new element added, the map is destroyed)...

Comment: Likely a race condition due to `DebugAllocNew` being called from multiple threads. Or `DebugAllocNew` is called recursively when it tries to add items to the `map` which allocates memory by calling `DebugAllocNew`?

Comment: Why are you using `int` as a key type, when you're storing pointers?

Comment: What is the `x` value when it segfaults?

Comment: its just name i gave because it keeps track on how many new is created

Comment: Are you calling that function from the constructor of some other global?

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to re-write your code to below code, no mixed C/C++ code, no global variables etc, more C++ way:

```
typedef map<int,string> DebugAllocPtrList_t;    

void incrementCount()
{
  static int g_DebugAllocCount = 0;
  g_DebugAllocCount++;
}

std::string makeString(const std::string& file, int line)
{
  std::stringstream ss;
  ss << file << " line " << line;
  return ss.str();
}

void DebugAllocNew(DebugAllocPtrList_t& ptr_map, int x, const std::string& file, int line)
{  
  std::cout <<"Memory already allocated" <<std::endl;
  ptr_map[x] = makeString(file, line);

  incrementCount();
}

int main()
{  
  DebugAllocPtrList_t t;

  DebugAllocNew(t, "something", 1, 2);
  DebugAllocNew(t, "something", 1, 2);
}
```